# chave primária como como char

Tags: java

Tenho uma tabela como chave primaria um `char(1)` no sql server usando o driver jtds.

```
public class Situacao{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "cod_sit_pedi_aval")
private Character codSitPediAval;

}

public class Pedido{

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cod_sit_pedi_aval")
private Situacao situacao;
}
```

Só que quando vou atualizar recebo o seguinte erro: IJ031042: Method is not implemented by JDBC driver

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
>   at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:1274)
>   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:1466)
> ```

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Acho que não dá pra usar o `GeneratedValue` com campo `Character`. Esse campo não é pré-definido, numa carga ou algo assim?

Comment: Vou trocar aqui